# Evaluation and Truncation

Tags: c, truncation

What occurs first, truncation or evaluation? If I do this:

```
int a = (2+3)*10.5;
```

a gets 52, but if I do this:

```
int a = 30 / 4 * 5;
```

a gets 35.

So an expression is evaluated first and then truncated. Then the truncated value is used for other calculations? 'Cause in the second statement "30/4" is evaluated first and then it gets truncated to 7. What are the exact rules for this? Anything from the documentation... I'm not talking about type conversion, just truncation in this case, like expressions get truncated one after the other?

Comment: Use operator precedence to deduct the types of the data.... if `/` and `*` have the same precedence and left associativity, they will be executed as `(30 / 4) * 5`, won't they?  `30 / 4 => 7` and `7 * 5 => 35`. Right?  No truncation, you are dividing two integers, and get an `int` result.  Try `30.0 / 4 * 5` and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're kind of asking the wrong question, there's no such thing as separate evaluation and truncation steps. Truncation is a side effect of a type conversion, if the converted value can't be represented exactly in the target type, like

```
double d = 2.5;
int i = d;       // 2.5 is truncated as a side effect of converting to int
```

So what you have to know is how operands are converted when evaluating an expression. The exact rules are a bit complicated, I'll focus on the basics here. In general, with arithmetic operators, if the operands don't have the same type already, one of them is converted in a way so both values can be represented. In your first example:

```
int a = (2+3)*10.5;
```

`2` and `3` are both of type `int`, so they're just added -- the result (`5`) has type `int` again.

But `10.5` has type `double`. So, `5` is converted to `double` as well, the result is `52.5`. Only because you assign that to an `int`, it gets converted back to `int` and therefore, truncation must take place.

In your second example:

```
int a = 30 / 4 * 5;
```

Both `30` and `4` have the type `int`. Therefore, no conversion takes place and the division is carried out directly.

**Here's the catch:** dividing two integers is an **integer division** which again results in an `int` (here: `7`). That's not truncation, it's just how integer divisions are defined. In fact, you probably learned about that operation early in school, using an algorithm called [long division with remainder](https://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division2.html). There's an "opposite" operation modulo (`%`) in C which would give you the *remainder* of that division.

So, here you have the result `7` of type `int`, which is then multiplied by `5`, another `int`, therefore, again, no conversion -- the final result is `35`.

Check what happens if you write

```
int a = 30.0 / 4 * 5;
```

instead. Now, the first operand of `/` is a double, so `4` is converted to `double` as well and the result is `7.5` -- which is again a `double`, causing the `5` to be converted to a `double` and yielding the final result of `37.5`.

This is again converted to `int` because you assign it to an `int` and truncation yields `37`.

---

Note how the operator `/` means two different things here (real division vs integer division), depending on the type of its operands.

Answer (score 4):

What happens depends on the types of the values involved.

`2`, `3`, `30`, `4`, and `5` are all of type `int`.

`10.5` has type `double`.

Thus `(2+3)*10.5` performs integer addition of `2` and `3`, yielding `5` (another `int`), then floating-point multiplication of `5.0` (implicitly converted from `5`) and `10.5`, yielding `52.5`. This number is assigned to an `int`, which implicitly truncates it to `52`.

On the other hand, in `30 / 4 * 5` all operands are `int`s and nothing is converted to `double`. Thus `30 / 4` performs integer division, yielding `7`, which is then multiplied by `5`, yielding `35`.

There is no separate evaluation and truncation. Truncation can happen as part of type conversion, but in `30 / 4` you're not looking at separate truncation and evaluation steps, but a single operation (integer division). Of course, since the result of this has type `int`, it can't have any decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think in terms of *truncation* and *evaluation*. Instead, think in terms of *grouping* and *integer division*. There are some other terms to be introduced for adequate analysis: I've taken care to *italicise* those.

The *expression* `(2 + 3) * 10.5` is explicitly grouped due to the parentheses. So `5 * 10.5` is an intermediate step; this is a `double` type as `5` is converted from an `int` to a `double`. The value of this expression is `52.5` which is truncated to `52` when assigned to an `int`.

`30 / 4 * 5` is *grouped* from left to right (multiplication and division have the same *precedence* so the *associativity* of the operators comes into play), so it's equivalent to `(30 / 4) * 5`. `30 / 4` is `7` (integer division), and that is multiplied by `5` to get the result.

A more interesting example is `30 / 4 * 5.0`. That is *still* `35` but is a `double` type. The grouping remains as `(30 / 4) * 5.0`.